# Electrical Machines and Transformers

Tags: power-engineering

Why do we multiply by the square root of 3 to get the phase to phase voltage from the phase to neutral voltage? What would be the multiplication factor for a 6-phase system, where the adjacent phases are separated by 60° instead of 120°?

Comment: The phase to (adjacent) phase voltage in a 6 phase system is identical to the phase to neutral voltage: The maxima of `sin(x) - sin(x + 2*pi/6)` comes out as 1, while the maxima of  `sin(x) - sin(x + 2*pi/3)` resolves predictably to sqrt(3). You can verify this with wolfram alpha. I'd be interested in the actual derivation of the result, if somebody could spare the effort.

Answer (score 3):

Good morning!

To get to the result that line to line voltage(Vl) is phase voltage(Vp)*3^1/2, you need to analize the phasorial diagram:

[image]

Follow the same procedure to find the relation between Vp and Vl for any poliphase electric system.
**For hexaphase system you´ll find Vl=Vp**, thats because the angle between phase voltages is 60º.

Have a good day!